# update multiple attributes in jsonb using case statement psql

Tags: sql, json, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

I am trying to update the jsonb column **media**, with two keys i.e 
`default`** is of type jsonb and `image_set` is an array of jsonb.

Is there is solution for single select update statement to update both keys.
test_media table

```
id |                                                                         media                                                                         | name  
----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------
  2 | {"default": {"w1": "fff", "w2": "aaa", "w3": "ddd"}, "image_set": [{"w1": "fff", "w2": "aaa", "w3": "ddd"}, {"w1": "bbb", "w2": "rrr", "w3": "vvv"}]} | pooja
```

#### Updating image-set

```
Update test_media 
  set media = media #- ('{image_set,'||(select pos-1 from test_media, jsonb_array_elements(media->'image_set') with ordinality arr(value, pos) where name='pooja' and value->>'w1'='fff') 
                       || '}')::text[] 
                       || jsonb_set(media, '{default}', '{"w1": "bbb", "w2": "rrr", "w3": "vvv"}' )
where name='pooja';
```

Here, based on delete, I want to update the default and image_set together depends on different condition.**default** jsonb value is from **image_set** array. I tried using case statement but it is not working fine. Different conditions of delete are :

1. When the jsonb value, i want to delete is in default as well as in
   image_set, it should delete that value from image set and update the
   default with other value from image set.
2. If not so, it won't update default, just the image_set value will be 
   deleted.
3. If the value of array i.e image_set is 1 , then the media='{}' updated 
   to null json.

Tried two things updating separately, default and image_set.

```
Update test_media 
   set media =  ( CASE 
                   WHEN jsonb_array_length(media->'image_set')::int > 1 
                      THEN (Select media #- ('{image_set,'||(select pos-1 from test_media , jsonb_array_elements(media->'image_set') with ordinality arr(value, pos) where name='pooja' and value->>'w1'='fff') || '}')::text[]) 
                   ELSE media = '{}' 
                   END IF
                ) 
where name='pooja';
```

Here, i got the error:CASE types boolean and jsonb cannot be matched
Secondly,

```
update test_media  
   set media = jsonb_set(media, '{default}', (select  from (select CASE WHEN media->'default'->>'w1'='fff' AND jsonb_array_length(media->'image_set')::int >0 THEN (select media->'image_set'->0 from test_media where name='pooja' ) WHEN  media->'default'->>'w1'='fff' AND jsonb_array_length(media->'image_set')::int = 0 THEN (select media - 'default' from test_media where name = 'pooja') END) As Sub), True) 
where name='pooja';
```

I would be thankful if i get support for case statement using select update. Hope for a positive response. Thanks.

[updating multiple jsonb column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46524806/update-multiple-jsonb-values)

[update-multiple-values-in-a-jsonb-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40583639/update-multiple-values-in-a-jsonb-data-in-postgressql)